# Vue 2.7 using v-slots without <template>

Tags: vue.js, vuejs-slots

I have a setup of 3 components - Wrapper, Parent, Controls

I'm rendering a Parent inside of Wrapper via a slot and I want to be able to render the Controls inside a named v-slot in the Wrapper component. I've achieved that like so:

Parent:

```
<Wrapper>
  <div class="parent">
    <template v-slot:controls>
      <Controls>
    </template>
  </div>
</Wrapper>
```

Wrapper:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <slot>
  <div class="controls">
    <slot name="controls">
  </div>
</div>
```

This works but I want to avoid using the `<template>`. Removing it and replacing v-slot with the *deprecated* `slot` prop seems to also work

```
<Wrapper>
  <div class="parent">
    <Controls slot="controls">
  </div>
</Wrapper>
```

but I'm looking for a way to achieve this cleaner syntax with `v-slot` instead. Is that possible or am I bound to using `template`?

Comment: It is `<template #controls>` https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Named-Slots-Shorthand